# Make table with images fill the whole page?

Tags: css

Something tells me that this question was already asked a thousand times, but I really tried searching and didn't find anything that solves my problem.

I'd like to create a 4x2 table filled with images so that the two table rows fill the whole screen, each taking exactly half of the page. The columns should be exactly 1/4 of width of the page. The cells should store images that will scale (most preferably, saving the aspect ratio), never resizing the cells. I'd prefer the sizes to be relative, always filling the whole screen.

How can I achieve that? Here's the closest I could get so far, with a screenshot below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
<title>piqdure</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    tr {
        height: 50%;
        max-height: 50%;
    }

    td {
        width: 25%;
        max-width: 25%;
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/19gdql5jauwbkgif/ku-medium.gif" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/85c03a3b9ef019411d5cfd68809390fc/tumblr_mjr01oYDsO1ql2603o1_400.gif" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/0e2318bb03b9f3b0b7cae374168d7b97/tumblr_n1fk1bbQVp1qzefipo1_400.gif" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/d96a634879926b0e2dc984ccdede3f6f/tumblr_n1f6ol68Be1s199fdo1_250.gif" alt=""/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://tnij.org/japierdole.jpg" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/7939e097500264cf1528a84e8b561f0a/tumblr_n0j91qyM4o1qb5gkjo1_500.gif" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/83f1a94515a820709bd98b13898b0d4a/tumblr_n0mnnxucgM1qzefipo1_250.gif" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdvesePMC51qgxioxo1_500.gif" alt=""/></td>

    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/8iHqKXY.jpg]

The problem here is the scrollbar on the right - I don't want `overflow: hidden`, I'd rather want to make it unnecessary by resizing the images.

Comment: "saving the proportions" - do you mean keep the same "aspect ratio"?

Comment: Note: `overflow: none` doesn't exist. It can be `visible`, `auto`, `scroll` or `hidden`.

Comment: Yes, you two are right. I clarified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8r6gw/)

HTML:

```
<div id="photos">
    <img src="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/19gdql5jauwbkgif/ku-medium.gif" alt="" />
    <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/85c03a3b9ef019411d5cfd68809390fc/tumblr_mjr01oYDsO1ql2603o1_400.gif" alt="" />
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/0e2318bb03b9f3b0b7cae374168d7b97/tumblr_n1fk1bbQVp1qzefipo1_400.gif" alt="" />
    <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/d96a634879926b0e2dc984ccdede3f6f/tumblr_n1f6ol68Be1s199fdo1_250.gif" alt="" />
    <img src="http://tnij.org/japierdole.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/7939e097500264cf1528a84e8b561f0a/tumblr_n0j91qyM4o1qb5gkjo1_500.gif" alt="" />
    <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/83f1a94515a820709bd98b13898b0d4a/tumblr_n0mnnxucgM1qzefipo1_250.gif" alt="" />
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdvesePMC51qgxioxo1_500.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#photos {
    height: 300px;
    font-size: 0; /* Remove spaces */
}
#photos > img{
    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Note: Only use tables for tabular data.

---

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8r6gw/14/)

It's also possible to define an aspect ratio for `#photos`:

HTML:

```
<div id="photos">
    <div id="photos-inner">
        <!-- Images -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#photos {
    font-size: 0; /* Remove spaces */
    position: relative;
}
#photos:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50%; /* aspect ratio */
}
#photos-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
}
#photos-inner > img{    
    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! After changing height to 100%, this seems to work like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @d33tah what about aspect ratio?

Comment: @chadocat Updated adding aspect ratio (for the container).

Comment: @Oriol OK aspect ratio requirement is now respected but the container still doesn't adapt to 100% height...

Comment: @chadocat Oh, I didn't read it must fill all screen. That makes it impossible to keep an aspect ratio, unless clipping the images like your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol) said, tables should be use for tabular data.

To follow your requirements :

1. adaptive img height and width,
2. use 100% width and height of window
3. keep aspect ratio and
4. no "gaps" betweeen images

The only way you can achieve your layout with only HTML/CSS is to use the `background-image` CSS property for your images with `background-size: cover;`.

**Solution :**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/8r6gw/15/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/19gdql5jauwbkgif/ku-medium.gif);">
    </div>
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://31.media.tumblr.com/85c03a3b9ef019411d5cfd68809390fc/tumblr_mjr01oYDsO1ql2603o1_400.gif);">
    </div>
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/0e2318bb03b9f3b0b7cae374168d7b97/tumblr_n1fk1bbQVp1qzefipo1_400.gif);">
    </div>
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://24.media.tumblr.com/d96a634879926b0e2dc984ccdede3f6f/tumblr_n1f6ol68Be1s199fdo1_250.gif);">
    </div>
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://tnij.org/japierdole.jpg);">
    </div>
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/7939e097500264cf1528a84e8b561f0a/tumblr_n0j91qyM4o1qb5gkjo1_500.gif);">
    </div>
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://24.media.tumblr.com/83f1a94515a820709bd98b13898b0d4a/tumblr_n0mnnxucgM1qzefipo1_250.gif);">       
    </div>
    <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdvesePMC51qgxioxo1_500.gif);">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body,html,#wrap {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.img{
    width:25%;;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
```